# Unity GooglePlayGamesPlugin package import issue

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to **import google play services in my Unity game** to get AdMob working through the IronSource Ad SDK.

The first step of importing the **GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.9.50.unitypackage** works well and I can get a nice *"The Google Play Games Plugin for Unity version 0.
9.50 is now ready to use"* popup.

After this step the Google Version Handler asks me to delete some obsolete files in my project (Google.IOSResolver.dll/JarResolver.dll and PackageManager.dll).

Finally there is this "Android Resolves Dependencies" step which is interrupted by this message :

> Android SDK packages need to be installed : * tools (26.1.1).

When I click yes, it seems to works, but a second popup message appears :

> Android SDK packages need to be installed : *
>   extras;android;m2repository

And here I'm stuck because when I click yes Unity logs this :

> Android SDK package extras;android;m2repository
>   (extra-android-m2repository) not installed or out of date.

I tried many many  solutions that I found here and there on google but nothing worked so far.

For information my **Android SDK and JDK are linked in the Unity preferences External tools**. And I can build on my Android device when I don't importe this package.

And the **Android Support Repository** (which contain the m2repository lib I guess) **package is installed via the Android SDK Manager**. I can also find the m2repository at this path : [...]android-sdk\extras\android (containing various files).

Thank you in advance for your help.